# Cannot create a subscriber with Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am getting an error when I make a subscriber in Vuex. I make a new subscriber for get my mutation details.

But I get the error

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

**Versions**

```
"Vue": "^2.6.11",
"Vue-router": "^3.1.6",
"Vuex": "^3.1.3"
```

**Subscriber**

```
import store from '@/store'

    store.subscribe((mutation) => {console.log(mutation);
})
```

I need to get my axios header details in my mutations. Can anyone help?

Comment: You don't show anything that could help answer this question. Error means that you fail to import your store, because it is undefined. How do you create the store? What's in the store? Where is the line that throws an error?

Comment: i fixed my error with using '../store' with defined store path instead of use '@/store/'